# Steam Launcher via Javascript - Semi Operational

Tags: javascript, firefox, steam, jsbin

This is weird...
The function works like a charm, but HTML is semi-operational. Firefox loads the program launcher, but it doesn't launch when I click OK.

Is this a programming issue? Or is it a Firefox problem?
Code: http://output.jsbin.com/tutoje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot put ID field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="steam game id" id="steamGameID">
```